¿Puedo vicular múltiples Widgets Entry a un solo widget Text, en tkinter?
Estoy desarrollando un programa donde quiero que las cajas de los "materiales" (todas son entry) se vinculen a la caja de "especificaciones" la cual es un Text, Esto por que me gustaria que si modificamos el texto en cualquier caja de material, de forma automática lo haga también la caja Text, pero sin que borre lo que ya esté escrito y conservando su posición. ¿Algo como eso es posible? Dejo una parte del código como ejemplo y una imagen:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog



from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk



import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

class Especificaciones_Impresion:
 def abrir_Ventana_Especificaciones():

        Especificaciones_Impresion.Opciones_clientes_Especificaciones()

        #Variables globales (Se utilizaran en varias funciones)
        global Texbox_Material_1,Texbox_Material_2,Texbox_Material_3,Texbox_Material_4,Texbox_Material_5
        global Texbox_Material_6,Texbox_Material_7,Texbox_Material_8,Texbox_Material_9,Texbox_Material_10
        global Texbox_Material_11, Texbox_Material_12, Texbox_Material_13,Texbox_Material_14,Texbox_Material_15
        global Texbox_Material_16,Texbox_Material_17,Texbox_Material_18,Texbox_Material_19,Texbox_Material_20
        global Texbox_Material_21,Texbox_Material_22,Texbox_Material_23,Texbox_Material_24,Texbox_Material_25
        global Texbox_Material_26,Texbox_Material_27,Texbox_Material_28,Texbox_Material_29,Texbox_Material_30
        global Caja_de_Especificaciones, Texbox_del_Codigo, Desplegable_del_Concepto,Ventana_especificaciones
        global Texbox_Proovedor, Texbox_Ejecucion, Texbox_Forma_de_Pago,Texbox_Cargos_adicionales,Textbox_de_las_unidades
        global Textbox_Referencias_1,Textbox_Referencias_2,Textbox_Referencias_3,Textbox_Referencias_4,Textbox_Referencias_5
        global Textbox_Referencias_6,Textbox_Referencias_7,Textbox_Referencias_8,Textbox_Referencias_9,Textbox_Referencias_10
        global Boton_Imprimir_Especificaciones, Caja_de_tratamiento, Texbox_Clave_Plano

        #Llamamos a la creación de la ventana
        Ventana_especificaciones = Tk()
        #Ventana_especificaciones.state('zoomed')
        Ventana_especificaciones.geometry("1200x720")
        Ventana_especificaciones.title("Especificaciones")

        Ventana_especificaciones.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(5,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(6,weight=1)
        Ventana_especificaciones.rowconfigure(7,weight=1)


        #Grupo de Especificaciones/Código/Conceptos/Unidades
        Grupo_de_Especificacion = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Especificaciones")

        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(5,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(6,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(7,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(8,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(9,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(10,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(11,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(12,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(13,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(14,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(15,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(16,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(17,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(18,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(19,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(20,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(21,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(22,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.columnconfigure(23,weight=1)

        Grupo_de_Especificacion.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Especificacion.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

        Grupo_de_Especificacion.grid(row=0,column=0,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label_del_Codigo = Label(Grupo_de_Especificacion, text="Código: ",width = 13, font=("arial",12))
        Label_del_Codigo.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        Label_del_Concepto = Label(Grupo_de_Especificacion, text="Concepto: ",width = 13, font=("arial",12))
        Label_del_Concepto.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=5,pady=5)
        Label_de_las_unidades = Label(Grupo_de_Especificacion, text="Unidades: ",width = 13, font=("arial",12))
        Label_de_las_unidades.grid(row=0,column=22,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_del_Codigo = Entry(Grupo_de_Especificacion)
        Texbox_del_Codigo.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=E+W)
        Texbox_del_Codigo.bind("<Return>",Especificaciones_Impresion.consultar_codigo)
        
        Textbox_de_las_unidades = Entry(Grupo_de_Especificacion)
        Textbox_de_las_unidades.grid(row=0,column=23,sticky=E+W,padx=10,pady=5)

        Desplegable_del_Concepto = Entry(Grupo_de_Especificacion)
        Desplegable_del_Concepto.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=10,pady=5,columnspan=18)
        #Desplegable_del_Concepto.bind("<Return>",Especificaciones_Impresion.consultar_concepto)

        Caja_de_Especificaciones = Text(Grupo_de_Especificacion,width=10,height=10)
        Caja_de_Especificaciones.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=24,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        #Grupo tratamiento de materiales
        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Escriba el manejo adecuado para los materiales")

        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

        Caja_de_tratamiento = Text(Grupo_de_tratamiento_de_materiales,width=10,height=10)
        Caja_de_tratamiento.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)


        #Grupo de Lista de materiales
        Grupo_de_Materiales = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Materiales")

        Grupo_de_Materiales.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.columnconfigure(3,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.columnconfigure(4,weight=1)

        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(4,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_Materiales.rowconfigure(5,weight=1)

        Grupo_de_Materiales.grid(row=4,column=0,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Material_1 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_2 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_3 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_4 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_5 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_6 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_7 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_8 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_9 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_10 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_11 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_12 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_13 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_14 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_15 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_16 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_17 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_18 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_19 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_20 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_21 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_22 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_23 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_24 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_25 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_26 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_27 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_28 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_29 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)
        Texbox_Material_30 = Entry(Grupo_de_Materiales)

        Texbox_Material_1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_4.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_5.grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_6.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_7.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_8.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_9.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_10.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_11.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_12.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_13.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_14.grid(row=2,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_15.grid(row=2,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_16.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_17.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_18.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_19.grid(row=3,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_20.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_21.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_22.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_23.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_24.grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_25.grid(row=4,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_26.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_27.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_28.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_29.grid(row=5,column=3,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Texbox_Material_30.grid(row=5,column=4,sticky=E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        #Grupo forma de pago
        Grupo_Forma_de_Pago = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Forma de pago")

        Grupo_Forma_de_Pago.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Forma_de_Pago.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        Grupo_Forma_de_Pago.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Forma_de_Pago = Entry(Grupo_Forma_de_Pago)
        Texbox_Forma_de_Pago.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)

        #Grupo ejecución
        Grupo_Ejecucion = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Ejecucion")

        Grupo_Ejecucion.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Ejecucion.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        Grupo_Ejecucion.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Ejecucion = Text(Grupo_Ejecucion,width=10,height=5)
        Texbox_Ejecucion.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)

        #Grupo referencias
        Grupo_de_referencias = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Referencias")
        Grupo_de_referencias.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Grupo_de_referencias.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)
        Grupo_de_referencias.rowconfigure(4,weight=1)

        Textbox_Referencias_1= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_2= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_3= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_3.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_4= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_4.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_5= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_5.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_6= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_6.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_7= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_7.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_8= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_8.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_9= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_9.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Textbox_Referencias_10= Entry(Grupo_de_referencias)
        Textbox_Referencias_10.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        #Grupo de proovedores
        Grupo_Proovedor = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Proovedor(es)")

        Grupo_Proovedor.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Proovedor.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        Grupo_Proovedor.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Proovedor = Entry(Grupo_Proovedor)
        Texbox_Proovedor.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        #Grupo de cargos adicionales
        Grupo_Cargos_adicionales = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Cargos adicionales")

        Grupo_Cargos_adicionales.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Cargos_adicionales.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        Grupo_Cargos_adicionales.grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Cargos_adicionales = Entry(Grupo_Cargos_adicionales)
        Texbox_Cargos_adicionales.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)

        #Grupo de clave de plano
        Grupo_Clave_Plano = LabelFrame(Ventana_especificaciones,text="Clave de plano")

        Grupo_Clave_Plano.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Clave_Plano.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        Grupo_Clave_Plano.grid(row=6,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Texbox_Clave_Plano = Entry(Grupo_Clave_Plano)
        Texbox_Clave_Plano.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W)

        #Grupo de botones
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones = Frame(Ventana_especificaciones)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.grid(row=6,column=0,rowspan=2,columnspan=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,pady=5,padx=5)

        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.rowconfigure(2,weight=1)
        Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones.rowconfigure(3,weight=1)

        BotonActualizar= Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Actualizar")
        BotonActualizar.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        BotonLimpiar= Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Limpiar")
        BotonLimpiar.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        BotonGuardar= Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Guardar")
        BotonGuardar.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Boton_Buscar_insumos = Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Consultar insumos")
        Boton_Buscar_insumos.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Boton_Abrir_edicion_PDF = Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Edición PDF")
        Boton_Abrir_edicion_PDF.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)

        Boton_Imprimir_Especificaciones = Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Imprimir especificación")
        Boton_Imprimir_Especificaciones.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5)
        Boton_Imprimir_Especificaciones.configure(state="disabled")

        Boton_Regresar_Interfaz = Button(Grupo_Opciones_Especificaciones,text="Regresar")
        Boton_Regresar_Interfaz.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=N+S+E+W,padx=5,pady=5) 
        

        Ventana_especificaciones.mainloop()


Quiero que las 30 estén vinculadas a la caja Text y la que modificación se haga en tiempo real, como si fuera una textvariable pero con todos, en primer lugar el widget Text no es compatible con textvariable y en segundo, aunque lo fuera solo podría vincular un solo entry y necesito que sean los 30. ¿algo así puede ser posible?
Añado un ejemplo de cómo funcionaría lo que quiero hacer:




Hola Fernando, ¿podrías aclarar como exactamente esa vinculación? "conservando su posición"¿qué posición exactamente le corresponde a cada entry?  ¿cada entry una linea, en columnas...? ¿Es el text editable? Si lo es ¿si se modifica el text se debe reflejar en los entries también?

Hola, Sevilla, por vinculación me refiero a que los entry estén "ligados" al Text. O sea que si yo hago una modificación al entry, esta se vea reflejada en el Text, pero no al revés, si modifico el Text no quiero que el entry se ve modificado. Daré un ejemplo concreto en otro comentario.

Yo en mi lista de materiales tengo: papel, tijeras y pegamento.
Entonces en la caja de especificaciones (el Text) aparecen esos tres materiales en orden: papel, tijeras y pegamento. Entonces yo edito el Text con lo siguiente: "Voy a crear una figura de papel, para ello primero necesito cortarlo con tijeras y pegarlo con pegamento

Pero resulta que me equivoqué y el material que voy a ocupar es silicón y no pegamento, entonces en la lista de materiales, en el entry donde escribí pegamento lo cambio a silicón, por lo tanto mi caja de Text debe actualizarse automáticamente y decir: "Voy a crear una figura de papel, para ello primero necesito cortarlo con tijeras y pegarlo con silicón"

Actualización, logré diseñar dos funciones que en conjunto pueden lograr esta meta:
def temporal():

    global textos_inicio, plano_inicio

    entries = [
        Texbox_Material_1, Texbox_Material_2, Texbox_Material_3, Texbox_Material_4, Texbox_Material_5,
        Texbox_Material_6, Texbox_Material_7, Texbox_Material_8, Texbox_Material_9, Texbox_Material_10,
        Texbox_Material_11, Texbox_Material_12, Texbox_Material_13, Texbox_Material_14, Texbox_Material_15,
        Texbox_Material_16, Texbox_Material_17, Texbox_Material_18, Texbox_Material_19, Texbox_Material_20,
        Texbox_Material_21, Texbox_Material_22, Texbox_Material_23, Texbox_Material_24, Texbox_Material_25,
        Texbox_Material_26, Texbox_Material_27, Texbox_Material_28, Texbox_Material_29, Texbox_Material_30
    ]

    textos_inicio = [entry.get() for entry in entries]

    
    plano_inicio = Texbox_Clave_Plano.get()

def btnActualizar():
    entries = [
        Texbox_Material_1, Texbox_Material_2, Texbox_Material_3, Texbox_Material_4, Texbox_Material_5,
        Texbox_Material_6, Texbox_Material_7, Texbox_Material_8, Texbox_Material_9, Texbox_Material_10,
        Texbox_Material_11, Texbox_Material_12, Texbox_Material_13, Texbox_Material_14, Texbox_Material_15,
        Texbox_Material_16, Texbox_Material_17, Texbox_Material_18, Texbox_Material_19, Texbox_Material_20,
        Texbox_Material_21, Texbox_Material_22, Texbox_Material_23, Texbox_Material_24, Texbox_Material_25,
        Texbox_Material_26, Texbox_Material_27, Texbox_Material_28, Texbox_Material_29, Texbox_Material_30
    ]

    textos_actualizado = [entry.get() for entry in entries]
    plano_actualizado = Texbox_Clave_Plano.get()

    longitud_textos_inicio=[]
    longitud_textos_actualizado=[]

    for contador in textos_inicio:
        if contador !="":
            longitud_textos_inicio.append(contador)
    
    for contador in textos_actualizado:
        if contador !="":
            longitud_textos_actualizado.append(contador)
    
    set1= set(textos_inicio)
    set2 = set(textos_actualizado)

    # Encontrar los elementos que están en lista1 pero no en lista2
    diferentes_en_lista1 = set1 - set2

    # Encontrar los elementos que están en lista2 pero no en lista1
    diferentes_en_lista2 = set2 - set1

    # Convertir los conjuntos resultantes en listas si es necesario
    diferentes_en_lista1 = list(diferentes_en_lista1)
    diferentes_en_lista2 = list(diferentes_en_lista2)
    
    if len(longitud_textos_actualizado)==len(longitud_textos_inicio):

        if diferentes_en_lista1 == []:
            if plano_inicio == "":
                Caja_de_Especificaciones.insert(INSERT,". Ver clave de plano: "+plano_actualizado+" P.U.O.T")
            
            else:
                Espec_obsoleta = Caja_de_Especificaciones.get("1.0",END)
                Espec_Actualizada = Espec_obsoleta.replace(". Ver clave de plano: "+plano_inicio+" P.U.O.T",". Ver clave de plano: "+plano_actualizado+" P.U.O.T")

                Caja_de_Especificaciones.delete("1.0",END)
                Caja_de_Especificaciones.insert(INSERT,Espec_Actualizada)


        else:

            Espec_obsoleta = Caja_de_Especificaciones.get("1.0",END)

            for contador in range(len(diferentes_en_lista1)):

                Espec_Actualizada=Espec_obsoleta.replace(diferentes_en_lista1[contador],diferentes_en_lista2[contador])
            
            Caja_de_Especificaciones.delete("1.0",END)
            Caja_de_Especificaciones.insert(INSERT,Espec_Actualizada)
        
        
    else:
        for contador in diferentes_en_lista2:
            Caja_de_Especificaciones.insert(INSERT,", "+contador)
            
    Especificaciones_Impresion.temporal()

En resumen, con la función temporal leeo todo lo que esté almacenado en la lista de materiales (Todos los Entry de materiales) además de leer también el contenido de la clave de plano. esta función se ejecuta al finalizar una consulta a la base de datos y vaciar todos estos datos en sus campor correspondientes. O sea primero consulto, vacío los datos y por último ejecuto la función temporal.
Una vez está todo almacenado en variables temporales, con el botón actualizar voy a comparar la lista que fue guardada anteriormente con la lista nueva de materiales, si hay una diferencia entre estas, entonces hará diferentes acciones, aplicando varios filtros (si se añadió un material nuevo, si se cambión uno de los materiales que ya estaban, etc.) Todos esos filtros se pueden ver en la función "BtnActualizar". Una vez hechas las comparaciones entrará a la caja de especificaciones y en caso de haber cambiado un materiales que ya estaba, entonces ese cambio se reflejará en la caja de especificaciones. Lo mismo aplicará para La clave del plano.


